# Polygonal chain in a rectangular parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, optimization

Given a rectangular parallelepiped **ABCDA1B1C1D1** with edges **AD = 6**, **AB = 8**, **AA1 = 8**. Points **M** and **N** are the middles of **A1B1** and **C1D1**. Points **E** and **F** are chosen on the edges **CC1** and **DD1** so that **C1E = 3**, **D1F = 7**. What is the minimal value of **AP+PQ**, where the point **P** lies somewhere on the line **MN**, and point **Q** lies somewhere on the line **EF**?
Wasted an hour looking for different approaches. But now I don't see the way through.
Need a good hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume
$$A=(0,0,0), \quad B=(8,0,0),\quad C=(8,6,0), \quad D=(0,6,0)\ ,$$
$$A_1=(0,0,8), \quad B_1=(8,0,8),\quad C_1=(8,6,8), \quad D_1=(0,6,8)\ .$$
Then $$N=(4,6,8),\quad F=(0,6,1),\quad E=(8,6,5),\quad P=(4,y,8)\ ,$$
where $y\in[0,6]$ has to be chosen optimally.

Given $P$,  the point $Q\in[FE]$ should be chosen such that
$$|PQ|^2=|PN|^2+|NQ|^2=(6-y)^2+|NQ|^2$$
is minimal, and this is the case if $NQ\perp FE$. The point $Q$ that solves this is the point $Q=(6,6,4)$, independently of $y$. For this choice of $Q$ we have $|NQ|^2=20$.

It follows that
$$|AP|+|PQ|=\sqrt{80+y^2}+\sqrt{(6-y)^2+20}=:f(y)\ .$$
Now we have to find the minimum of $f(y)$ in the closed $y$-interval $[0,6]$. I can leave this to you; Mathematica tells me that the optimal $y$ is a rational number.